# Python - crawl from an image in html (of which the source code is actually a paragraph)

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl data from the following image on a website,

[image: The display on the website]

And the source code of the corresponding image is shown below:

[image: Source code]

I want to use Python to extract the data from the image and make it readable. However, as the structure of the source code is only a paragraph, I have no clue how to structure the data / make the paragraph more readable. (Or I should say my very first question was that why a paragraph like this can be displayed as an image like that) I'm new to BeautifulSoup and html so any suggestions / guidance are appreciated. If I'm going in the wrong direction, please also point it out.

If you need, check the website that I want to pull our the information:
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/104169/000167276417000039/p55218_def14a.htm

---

Ideally, the output would be something like the following text (or table), having similar structure of the original image so it's easy to tell which number is which. For this certain example, I can definitely write customized function to split the paragraph and display like below, but is there a more generalized way to structure the paragraph in the source code so it's more readable?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what exactly you want to extract? show us how you want the extracted data to look like

Comment: You want to extract the image or data inside the image?

Comment: thanks to @Ahmad for directing me to think through about what I want. Please see the updated question with an example output.

Comment: thanks @drec4s .I want to only extract the data inside the image, while preserving the easy-to-read structure

Comment: I think you answered your question, since this is plain text inside a paragraph, there is no way to extract it without writing your own custom function to do it.

Comment: @drec4s yep I guess you are right... thanks for pushing me to think this through! However, I'm still confused why a paragraph can be displayed like that in the html...

Answer (score 0):

> the source code of the corresponding image is shown below
>
> why a paragraph like this can be displayed as an image like that

It's not though. That paragraph is not the source code of the image and it's not displayed as an image. The site you linked has the image & the paragraph of text, side by side & "independent" of each-other.

I.e. the image is just an image (& accessable via its direct url: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/104169/000167276417000039/p55218x61x1.jpg):
[image]

And the paragraph of text is just a paragraph of text:

```
<p style="font: 1pt Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; margin: 0pt 0; color: White">
    Total Company Threshold (37.5%) Target (100% payout) Max (125% Payout) Actual $23,660 No Payout $21,486 $22,840 $23,083 Walmart U.S. No Payout $17,101 $17,813 $17,902 International No Payout $5,477 $5,928 $5,987 Adjusted Constant Currency Sales (excluding fuel)* Total Company No Payout Actual $483,559 $473,456 $483,384 $485,855 Actual $306,287 Walmart U.S. No Payout $300,526 $306,346 $307,878 Actual $121,590 International No Payout $118,702 $120,962 $121,566
</p>
```

One does not create another in this case.

Note how the paragraph with the information you need has the font style set to be `1pt` and to be colored `White` (on an already white background). Basically the text is there but it's made invisible to the human eye. There isn't an easy way to read texts out of images so the likely reason that paragraph is there at all is so that the information on that web-page could be indexed by search engines (if it only consisted of imaged without paragraphs of texts like that - search engines would have a hard time understanding what was going on on that page). Though there could be other reasons as well (like it was a pdf file initially converted into an HTML page by a software that left that paragraph there for whatever reasons whether on purpose or not).

Now, while it's actually good that they have the text versions of the data - unfortunately the way it's structured (pretty much no structure at all, just appended data) makes it difficult to parse the end result and though it would still be possible - there's no reason to do that as if you look around at other parts of that report (for example on page 64) - you'll see that there's a text version of that same data in a nicely formatted table which would be a lot easier to parse and the image you initially pointed at was likely generated from the table here.

If that doesn't help and you still need the data from images which can't be found as text in the source of that page & since the page itself looks like it was automatically generated by a software from something else - you'd likely have better luck finding the original source of that data, if at all possible.